# Query Case Record Type Name for the Parent Case of an Email Message in SF

Tags: apex, soql, query, case, emailmessage

I want to query the Case Record Type Name for the Parent Case of an Email Message. I am trying with the below query but it is not returning me the name :-

```
select id,subject,parentid,parent.recordtypeid,parent.recordtype.name
   from emailmessage where id = 'xxx...xxx'
```

I am able to get the Record Type ID but not the name. In the name column, it is returning me [object Object].
Please advise if there is any way to do this.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

That's just an artifact of using the developer console.

If you use anonymous apex to run that query, and `system.debug(myEmailMessage.Parent.RecordType.Name);` (system.debug doesn't print nested objects, or does so very minimally) or `system.debug(JSON.serialize(myEmailMessage));`, you'll see that you do in fact get the data you requested in your query.

Comment: Can you please advise how to use that in a SOQL?

Comment: @SFDCAlex That request doesn't make any sense to me. The examples I gave simply use the result that you would get from a query.